# Protractor not able to execute else part of my code when element is not displayed/present

Tags: protractor

I always identify element on my screen with isDisplayed/isPresent and then add if/else to perform further test. But else part of the screen never get executed and get error like "Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, .noga-selected-summary.list.ng-scope.layout-row)" on console log.

Test_PO.js is as follow,

```
var ProfilePO = function(){
this.Setting = element.all(by.css('.md-icon-button.md-button.md-dark-theme.md-ink-ripple')).get(1);
this.SettingSubMenus = element.all(by.css('.md-tab.ng-scope.ng-isolate-scope.md-ink-ripple'));
//this.ReqProductLabel = element(by.css('[ng-show="ngModel && ngModel.length > 0"]'));
this.BusinessPage = element(by.css('[ng-model="required_categories"]'));
this.AddProductButton = element(by.css('[ng-click="addCategory()"]'));
this.AddedProdCat = element.all(by.css('.noga-selected-summary.list.ng-scope.layout-row'));
this.DeleteAddedProd = element.all(by.css('[ng-click="removeCategory(category)"]'));};
 module.exports = ProfilePO;
```

test_spec.js is as follow,

```
    it('Verify user can add required products on business screen using Find Product or Service Dropdown', function() {
    Profile.AddedProdCat.get(0).isDisplayed().then(function(AddedProdCatIsDisplayed){
        console.log('Added Prod Cat Is Displayed: ' + AddedProdCatIsDisplayed);
        if (AddedProdCatIsDisplayed) {
            Profile.AddedProdCat.count().then(function(count){
                var Count1 = count;
                var C1 = Count1-1;
                console.log('Product list has ' + count + ' products');
                for (var i=0, j=0; i <= C1 ; i++) {
                    Profile.DeleteAddedProd.get(j).click();
                    console.log('deleted ' + (i+1) + ' product');
                    browser.sleep(2000);
                }
            });
        } else {
            FuncLib.NogaList.isDisplayed().then(function(NogaListIsDisplayed) {
                console.log('Find Product or Service Dropdown Is Displayed: ' + NogaListIsDisplayed);
                if (NogaListIsDisplayed) {
                    FuncLib.SltNogaCat("A011100"); //select Noga
                    Profile.AddProductButton.isDisplayed().then(function (AddProdButtonDisplayed){
                        console.log('Add product button is displayed: ' + AddProdButtonDisplayed);
                        Profile.AddProductButton.click();
                        browser.sleep(3000);
                        Profile.AddedProdCat.isDisplayed().then(function(AddedProdCatIsDisplayed){
                            console.log('Added Prod Cat Is Displayed: ' + AddedProdCatIsDisplayed);
                            expect(Profile.AddedProdCat.getText()).toEqual('A011100');
                        });
                    });
                } else
                    console.log('Noga Catagory dropdown is not displayed');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

When"added product category list" is available on screen, this script works nicely but if I don't have added product category list, it returns above mentioned error. I tried using isPresent instead of isDisplayed but still I get same error. Kindly tell me what I need to do to handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `this.AddedProdCat` takes some time to get displayed.

You can use just wait using `Expected Conditions` for that element, something like this -

```
it('Verify user can add required products on business screen using Find Product or Service Dropdown', function() {

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(Profile.AddedProdCat.get(0)), 5000);
Profile.AddedProdCat.get(0).then(function(firstElement){
     console.log('Added Prod Cat firstElement: ' + firstElement);
     if (firstElement) {
        Profile.AddedProdCat.count().then(function(count){
            var Count1 = count;
            var C1 = Count1-1;
            console.log('Product list has ' + count + ' products');
            for (var i=0, j=0; i <= C1 ; i++) {
                Profile.DeleteAddedProd.get(j).click();
                console.log('deleted ' + (i+1) + ' product');
                browser.sleep(2000);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: it's giving me error: Failed: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: EC.visibilityOf(Profile.AddedProdCat.get(0)) will return function object, your if condition will never be 'false'.

Comment: @Xotabu4 Yes, You are right it returns a promise need to resolve it, kinda rushed it up! thanks for pointing :) updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

What version of protractor you are using? This should be fixed starting from 3.3.0 - https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/bd78dfc79b1435d124c994482df6879066079a4d

Comment: I have Protractor v3.2.2. do I need to update to higher version?

Comment: @SonalDalal Definitely you should. Always try to use newest versions of protractor (since new browser versions might not work with old protractor), but current latest 4.0.3 seems to be not really stable, and has some breaking changes. So as first step try to update to 3.3.0, it should be easy-update.

Comment: I upgraded protractor to 3.3.0, but still It's not working.